# How can I add multiple kafka broker in spring boot application?

Tags: apache-kafka

I have two kafka broker. I need to listen to both. How can I add both of them in my application.properties file?

```
test.kafka.bootstrapservers=Broker1:9092
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`bootstrap-servers` allows a comma-delimited list of host:port pairs to use for establishing the initial connections to the Kafka cluster.

You can add multiple Kafka nodes with a comma such as `localhost:9092,localhost:9095`.

For more information please refer [here](https://www.maestralsolutions.com/spring-boot-implementation-for-apache-kafka-with-kafka-tool/)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a valid Kafka cluster, then bootstrapping against only one will already cause you to consume from both.

Listing multiple bootstrap addresses is primarily for fault tolerance for the client and can be done with a comma-separated list